# How to disable back button on android device on specific dialog

Tags: android, c++, qt

In specific dialog I want to disable the back button on Android. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401484/where-to-control-the-qwizard-button), but I have an error:

> expected unqualified-id before '->' token CLanguageDialogManager->button(QWizard::BackButton)->setEnabled(false);

Here is my code:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QWizard>
#include "languagedialog.h"

CLanguageDialogManager::CLanguageDialogManager(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    // ...
    CLanguageDialogManager->button(QWizard::BackButton)->setEnabled(false);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: what do you want? Means dialog cancellation false or backbutton?

Comment: @user3676184 I want to disable physical back button on this dialog

Comment: then search foe dialog.setcancellable(false) in android

Comment: Use dialog.setcancelable(false)

Comment: is this is your android code

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. Your syntax is wrong. `CLanguageDialogManager` is the name of your class, but the function you want to call - `button()` - is a class member. Rather than writing

`CLanguageDialogManager->button(QWizard::BackButton)->setEnabled(false);`

you should write

`this->button(QWizard::BackButton)->setEnabled(false);`

2. The function you want to call - `button()` - is a member of QWizard, not a member of QDialog. It looks like 
   CLanguageDialogManager inherits QDialog, perhaps you mean for it to inherit QWizard instead. If so, your constructor should begin 
   `CLanguageDialogManager::CLanguageDialogManager(QWidget *parent):QWizard(parent)`